# How to ensure a certain datapoint is not in the test set in stratified cross validation split?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a DataFrame that looks like this.

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'col2': ['a', 'a','b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df

  col1  col2
0   1     a
1   2     a
2   3     b
3   4     b
4   5     c
5   6     c
6   7     d
7   8     d
```

When I use **k-fold cross validation**, I want to ensure the values in col2 are present either only in the train set or in the test set. That is, during the split, if `df['col2'][0] = a`, and `df['col2'][1] = a`, then the rows with index 0 and 1 should both be in the train set, else in the test set. It should not be such that row 0 is in the train set and row 1 is in the test set.

Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit:** Is there a way to just split the DataFrame into two such that each part contains all the data points that have value `a` in `col2` in the first DataFrame or the second but not both? I tried using `groupby` but it returns an object and when I convert it to a dictionary, I am able to access it only by the keys, i.e `a, b, c, d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @Antoine Dubuis, I found an sklearn implementation of what I wanted to do - called [StratifiedGroupKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold).

It is still in development as of July 2021, but can be used from the development/nightly version. I advise creating a separate virtual environment to use it.

I have used it and it seems to work currently, so hope it will be released in a stable release soon.

Answer (score 2):

You can ensure that a variable value is present only on a set by performing a `GroupShuffleSplit` as follows:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GroupShuffleSplit

import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
    'col2': ['a', 'a','b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'],
    'label': [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

X = df[['col1', 'col2']]
y = df['label']
groups= df['col2']
gss = GroupShuffleSplit(n_splits=2, train_size=.8, random_state=42)
for train_idx, test_idx in gss.split(X, y, groups):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_idx], X.iloc[test_idx]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_idx], y.iloc[test_idx]
```

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. Will this also result in a stratified split between the train and test data? My label is actually a third column.

Comment: The problem is that sklearn offers only the possibility to have a `stratified` or a `group` split. There is no stratify grouped split. but you can write your own.

Comment: Thank you, that is really good to know. If I write my own stratify group split, would the correct approach be to group split it and then check the labels in each split and exchange those rows only? Or is there a different method to proceed?

Comment: I would perform a stratify split on the unique values of `col2` and then find the X samples that have these col2 values. But you cannot be sure that the resulting group will have the correct size. Depending on the representation of one value of col2, the resulting set might differ.

Comment: it seems that sklearn has it in the development phase already [here](https://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedGroupKFold), however I get an import error when I try to use it.

Comment: yes indeed, thanks for sharing this. You can use this feature by installing the nightly build version as follows: `pip install --pre --extra-index https://pypi.anaconda.org/scipy-wheels-nightly/simple scikit-learn`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234444/discussion-between-user42-and-antoine-dubuis).